# Full-fledged Watson Assistant integration for testing

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have implemented a chatbot with Watson Assistant. There is a preview link integration available but this has the disadvantage that HTML and emojis are not supported. Using [this](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-create-a-chatbot-in-facebook-messenger/) and [this](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-build-a-chatbot-with-watson-conversation-using-microsoft-botframework/) tutorial I can integrate my bot into Facebook Messenger and Skype. But this only works on local devices and I cannot easily distribute it to other people for testing.

What I would like to do is to let several people test my chatbot simulatenously on their own smartphone with full functionality (HTML rendering, emojis). The integration should be very easy for them, for example just opening a webpage or just adding the bot to their Facebook Messenger or Skype (not so many steps as in the above links).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork this repository and replace the credentials with yours:
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-simple

Then host it wherever you prefer (you can host it on IBM Cloud as part of the Lite account) and share the link with the people you want to test it.